# One Strange Sign of Number Theory

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Can anyone please tell me what  the red marked sign means?[image]

Comment: It might mean $10$ does *not* divide $(n-1)!+1$.

Comment: NB:  In most texts, this would probably be typeset as $\not\mid$ (with the slash through the symbol slanting a bit, so that it doesn't look like a malformed $+$).  It is typeset as `\not\mid` or `\nmid`.

Comment: Agree that "does not divide" is the likely meaning. Note that $(n-1)!$ is an even number for $n \geq 3$.